# How can we add WordPress to a subdirectory of a React App?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

We currently have a React Web app. We'd like to be able to add WordPress in a subdirectory of the application. So for example:

- The react app lives on https://examplesite.com
- We would like WordPress installed on https://examplesite.com/blog

Currently our app is containerized on AWS.

How would we go about doing this?

Comment: You wouldn't accomplish this in React. There are a number of ways to do this depending on how your app is served and whether your app uses routing - why not create a DNS record for "blog.examplesite.com" and have it point to your WordPress IP?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that worked for me:

1. You need to have PHP server.
2. Build your react app and upload via FTP to public_html.
3. Upload wordpress to public_html/blog folder and setup db for it.
4. Update your .htaccess file for React routing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated: as @Brendan Bond suggest, you would need to setup a web server to serve the wordpress setup. You cannot just put the wordpress folder under a react app to make it work. However if you want to set up wordpress in a subfolder, you can follow the step below.

I would assume you know how to config the web server which serves wordpress. You would need to work through the following steps.

1 Take the official wordpress guide as the reference, config wordpress to work under the path:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/

2 Config the web server which serves wordpress (e.g. apache2) and make sure https://examplesite.com/blog is pointing to your wordpress installation

3 Put the link (https://examplesite.com/blog) in your react app and test if you can visit the wordpress site properly.